# Reading directory and files in directory using php

Tags: php, file

i have a code for reading folder and files in that folder.
Basically, what this code will do that it will show all files.And create the link for them.When I click on the link file will be open in the browser(if supported, like image) or downloaded.
But the problem is it's showing the files but not opening them.
Can any body highlight the problem, please?
here is full code.

```
<?php
$msgz = "";

if($handle = opendir('.'))
{
 while (false !== ($filez = readdir($handle)))
 {
 if (($filez != ".") && ($filez != ".."))
 {
 $msgz .= '<li><a href="'.$filez.'">'.$filez.'</a></li>';

 }

 }
 closedir($handle);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>List files and directories inside the specified path in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List files and directories inside the specified path in PHP</h2>
<p>List of files:</p>
<ul>
<p><?php echo $msgz ?></p>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the screenshot of browsers.

[image showing that link of the desired file is present in address bar but file is not open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufPN9.png)

Comment: What exactly is the result that you see? This code works for me.

Comment: It's not opening the files. like I want to open a jpeg file and it should open in the browser but it didn't. It's just showing the file name in the address bar.

Comment: That sounds more like a browser issue. So what is the browser's document like? Blank? Screenshot could help

Comment: can you share your e-mail with me so we can discuss it there? or how to share screenshot here. sorry I'm new to StackOverflow

Comment: @BartK i've attach the screenshot. can you please take a look?

Comment: What server are you using? It might be .htaccess redirecting all the traffic to your index.php

Comment: I'm using xampp loacl server

Comment: @BartK you were right there was some problem with the "index" I rename the file to "index.php" and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your file to index.php it will work.